# How to select two files and upload them?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am using AutoIt in Selenium WebDriver to select and upload a file. I want to select multiple files to upload. There is a button "upload" to open the file explorer.

AutoIt script:

```
ControlFocus(" Open "," ","Edit1" )
Global $files="",$appendquotes="",$j=2;
IF $cmdLine[0]==1 then
   $files=$CmdLine[1]
ElseIf $cmdLine[0] > 1 Then
   For $i=1 to $cmdLine[1]
      $appendquotes='"' & $CmdLine[$j] & '"';
      $files=$files & " " & $appendquotes;
      $j=$j+1;
   Next
EndIf

ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","D:\tfs\colors.TIF" "D:\tfs\colors1.TIF")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Java class code:

```
DriverOperations.clickWhenElementIsClickable(upload);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\AutoIT\\FileUploadMulti.exe");
```

Comment: Is it possible manually to upload two files in single modal window ?

Comment: yes it is, i can select multiple files.

Comment: The errormessage tells you there is a syntax error with the `ControlSetText` command. Did you mean `ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","D:\tfs\colors.TIF D:\tfs\colors1.TIF")` or `ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",'"D:\tfs\colors.TIF" "D:\tfs\colors1.TIF"')`?

Comment: i have written exact same which is on question, its saying invalid file, when the exe runs on a browser

Comment: @Stephan i am able to select this both files, with ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",'"D:\tfs\colors.TIF" "D:\tfs\colors1.TIF"') this one. Thank you very much.     can you please give me idea how can i achieve select all the files from the folder. like if i have 100 files in the same folder and i want all them selected and uploaded.

Comment: don't ask for file(s), but for the folder (or extract the folder from the full qualified filename) and process all files in that folder.